# Ruby: automatically wrapping methods in event triggers

Tags: ruby, events, metaprogramming, observer-pattern

Heres what I have/want:

```
module Observable
  def observers; @observers; end

  def trigger(event, *args)
    good = true
    return good unless (@observers ||= {})[event]
    @obersvers[event].each { |e| good = false and break unless e.call(self, args) }
    good
  end

  def on(event, &block)
    @obersvers ||= {}
    @obersvers[event] ||= []
    @observers[event] << block
  end

end

class Item < Thing
  include Observable
  def pickup(pickuper)
    return unless trigger(:before_pick_up, pickuper)

    pickuper.add_to_pocket self

    trigger(:after_pick_up, pickuper)
  end

  def drop(droper)
    return unless trigger(:before_drop, droper)

    droper.remove_from_pocket self

    trigger(:after_drop, droper)
  end

  # Lots of other methods
end

# How it all should work
Item.new.on(:before_pickup) do |item, pickuper| 
  puts "Hey #{pickuper} thats my #{item}"
  return false # The pickuper never picks up the object
end
```

While starting on trying to create a game in Ruby, I thought it would be great if it could be based all around Observers and Events.  The problem is have to write all of these triggers seems to be a waste, as it seems like a lot of duplicated code.  I feel there must be some meta programming method out there to wrap methods with functionality.

Ideal Sceanrio:

```
class CustomBaseObject
   class << self
     ### Replace with correct meta magic
     def public_method_called(name, *args, &block)
       return unless trigger(:before_+name.to_sym, args)
       yield block
       trigger(:after_+name.to_sym, args)
     end
     ###
   end
end
```

And then I have all of my object inherit from this `Class`.

I'm still new to Ruby's more advanced meta programming subjects, so any knowledge about this type of thing would be awesome.

Comment: There is an Observable module in the [standard lib](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html) which might fit your needs.

Comment: Note that you've misspelled `observers` as `obersvers` in several spots above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a several ways to do it with the help of metaprogramming magic. For example, you can define a method like this:

```
def override_public_methods(c)
  c.instance_methods(false).each do |m|
    m = m.to_sym
    c.class_eval %Q{
      alias #{m}_original #{m}
      def #{m}(*args, &block)
        puts "Foo"
        result = #{m}_original(*args, &block)
        puts "Bar"
        result
      end
    }
  end
end

class CustomBaseObject
  def test(a, &block)
    puts "Test: #{a}"
    yield
  end
end

override_public_methods(CustomBaseObject)

foo = CustomBaseObject.new
foo.test(2) { puts 'Block!' }
# => Foo
     Test: 2
     Block!
     Bar
```

In this case, you figure out all the required methods defined in the class by using `instance_methods` and then override them.

Another way is to use so-called 'hook' methods:

```
module Overrideable
  def self.included(c)
    c.instance_methods(false).each do |m|
      m = m.to_sym
      c.class_eval %Q{
        alias #{m}_original #{m}
        def #{m}(*args, &block)
          puts "Foo"
          result = #{m}_original(*args, &block)
          puts "Bar"
          result
        end
      }
    end
  end
end

class CustomBaseObject
  def test(a, &block)
    puts "Test: #{a}"
    yield
  end

  include Overrideable
end
```

The `included` hook, defined in this module, is called when you `include` that module. This requires that you `include` the module at the end of the class definition, because `included` should know about all the already defined methods. I think it's rather ugly :)