# How to implement before_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can anyone tell me the idea to implement the rail's before_filter method?(I want to try to write my own before_method)

Particularly, I wonder if ruby has some method to detect method calling?

My thought is :

step1: `alias_method :old_method, :method`

step2: `alias_method :method, :wrapper_method`

step3: in `wrapper_method`, we first do something, then call `old_method`

Is there any problem?

Anyone has a better idea?

Comment: Can you describe more what you mean by `some method to detect method calling`? It sounds like you are asking whether you can trigger an event when a particular method is called, but I am not certain if that is what you mean.

Comment: @Teeg, yes, that exactly what I mean. If I can do that, I think I can add something before running the method.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand. I've never really done this before, but this person posted [an interesting answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316228/ruby-automatically-wrapping-methods-in-event-triggers) that somewhat addresses what you want. The way he does it is basically to create an alias of the target function, then override the original with a new function which calls the aliased original...not exact what you wanted or straight forward, but that's about all I can see.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a method to be fired before calling any other method, you can do this with simply `before_filter`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :check_something
    ... 
    ... 
    ...
end
```

in this way the `check_something` method will be called before calling any method of this class.

Also you can restrict this by setting `only` or `except` option. Like

```
before_filter :check_something, :only =. [:show, :edit]
```

In this case the `check_something` method will be called only for `show` and `edit`.

May be the [before_filter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter) and [after_filter](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/after_filter) article worth taking a look.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not describe my answer well. What I mean is I want to implement rails's before_fileter by myself and wonder how..

Comment: Well if it just for learning purpose then better to know that rails framework does this by maintaining a `filter_chain` and for every call to its any controller method it follows the same sequence. The sequence is to call the methods from `before_filter_chain` first, then call the actual method and then call the methods from `after_filter_chain`. There may be some other stuffs between these. Take a look in `apidock/rails` on this. But if it is not only for learning, then it would be better to know the actual purpose.

Comment: Thx, I'm just for learning. I will look into rails source code.

Comment: I read the source code, but still confused. Yeah, I noticed that rails maintains a chain, but how does it know when to run it? I mean, for example, if I set a before_filter to class Dog's bark method, then I call dog.bark, the rails framework should capture my calling and run the filter first instead. My questions is how does rails' framework capture my calling to a particular method? I do not find it from the source code.